# CodeIgniter Pagination Order By Date Results Are Ordered Wrong And Displaying Same Results

Tags: codeigniter, datetime, pagination, sql-order-by

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  I've looked all over, but can't find what I'm looking for.  I'm trying to order my results by date.  I'm not sure if it would help to know that the dates are not in order in the table though.  I'm getting similar results on each page instead of loading the next set of records and the dates are out of order.

```
**Model**

<?php

class Topics_Model extends CI_Model {

    public $db_table_name = 'px_topics';

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function record_count()
    {
        return $this->db->count_all($this->db_table_name);
    }

    public function fetch_topics($limit, $offset)
    {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        $this->db->order_by("date", "desc");
        $query = $this->db->get($this->db_table_name);

        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
}

**Controller**

<?php

class Test extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->model('topics_model');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data['users'] = $this->user_model->get_all();
        $data['sessid'] = $this->user_model->get_by_sess_id();
        $data['sessdata'] = $this->user_model->get_session_data();
        $data['main_content'] = 'test_view';
        $this->load->view('template', $data);
    }

    function paged()
    {
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "test/paged";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->topics_model->record_count();
        $config["per_page"] = 5;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
        $config["use_page_numbers"] = TRUE;
        $config["next_tag_open"] = '<div class="next">';
        $config["next_tag_close"] = '</div>';
        //$choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
        //$config["num_links"] = round($choice);
        $config["num_links"] = "3";

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data["results"] = $this->topics_model->fetch_topics($config["per_page"], $page);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data["main_content"] = 'test2_view';

        $this->load->view('template', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you include the base url and a url generated by the pagination links, if they are displaying the same records usually the uri segment is not set correctly

Comment: I have my base url and index page setup like this, because I've set this up with clean urls...  $config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: yes but you have set your uri segment to  $config["uri_segment"] = 3; so you need the pagination parameter to be something like domain.com/home/pages/$no if it isn't like this you will get the same content returned by your query

Comment: I don't understand the last variable segment...

Comment: Try without 'use_page_numbers' config

Comment: what's the url is generated by the create_links() function

Comment: @ahmad You see that does work, but that breaks my infinite scroll which was why I was using the pagination class =/

Comment: I'm using the paulirish/infinite-scroll.  There's a subtle difference in the markup when not using page numbers shown here and I'm not sure why it breaks the infinite scroll....  [link](http://pastebin.com/QpCDH6Aa)

Comment: @ChrisMccabe - You can see the html source at the link I provided in the last comment for both with and without use_page_numbers

Comment: Well, I haven't figured this out yet, but I imagine it's all in the offset. When use_page_numbers is set to FALSE, this works perfectly, but breaks my infinite-scroll jquery plugin by Paul Irish.  When it's set to true the plugin works nicely, but the results are jacked.  Apparently the offset cannot be set to    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? ($this->uri->segment(3) * $config["per_page"]) - $config["per_page"] : 0;
```

This works :)